# how do i use .htaccess to redirect different languages to different pages?

Tags: html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to make a simple 2-language site, en and th, I am unfamiliar with .htaccess but found an online tool: http://www.htaccesstools.com/redirection-by-language/

I would like English browsers to go to my root folder's index.html, and Thai browsers to a subfolder.

What I got from the generator is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} th [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.mysite.com/th/index.html [R,L]
```

This doesn't work and I get a redirect loop/other error. I've tried changing the url on the last line to be relative, but this doesn't affect it.

Any help?

*to confirm, i have one .htaccess in my root folder only

Comment: Are you doing anything to stop /th/index.html from being redirected yet again? As I recall, Apache's rules tend to be hereditary. (But don't take my word for it.)

Comment: nope, and i couldn't find out how to do this.. if you can help at all that would be great. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/th/index.html|.*\.(woff|ttf|svg|js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|htc|xml|txt))$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^th [NC]
RewriteRule .* /th/index.html [R,L,QSA,NE]
```